# ReCaptcha IFrame Sandbox ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key

Tags: iframe, recaptcha, sandbox, invisible-recaptcha

Sorry, it has been a few days I still cannot find the error's solution yet. 
However, I suspect existing `<iframe>` as a parent element in my project may cause the errors the ReCaptcha `<iframe>` as a child element ***ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key***.

I already added the domain in ReCaptcha admin

You can see the code here.

```
<iframe 
    class="spg-preview d-block mx-auto" 
    sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-scripts" 
    srcdoc=" 
              <html> 
                  ...
                  <div name="recaptcha" data-recaptcha="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-siteKey="6LcR8NoUAAAAAMV3gFvR1z3Bdnn7QzErjrUi3fme"></div> 
                  ...
              </html>
           "
>

  <html>
       <head> ... </head>

       <div name="recaptcha" data-recaptcha="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcR8NoUAAAAAMV3gFvR1z3Bdnn7QzErjrUi3fme">
           <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
              <div>
                <iframe 
                    src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LcR8NoUAAAAAMV3gFvR1z3Bdnn7QzErjrUi3fme&amp;co=YWJvdXQ6&amp;hl=en&amp;v=f1wAZV34wmOO4-wA3kszbUcM&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=w38479ylabk0" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-deb0wlr3cthh" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
                    sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe></div>
                <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
              </div>
           <iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>
       </div>
  </html>
 
</iframe>
```

I already test both parents `iframe`

```
<iframe 
  class="spg-preview d-block mx-auto" 
  sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-scripts"

or

<iframe 
  class="spg-preview d-block mx-auto" 
  sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"
```

Does anybody know what it is exactly causing errors and solutions here?

[image]

Comment: I have same issue. Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @development-ninja, I don't know how to fix it, but I used another way. The web I developed has 2 features preview and publish. User can preview their page before publishing, so in the preview is used iframe as the Recaptcha's iframe then it causes the error. but when users publish, it's working fine because there is no parent iframe to cover the Recaptcha's iframe. So, the product owner suggested me fixing it by informing users that "Recaptcha in the preview display not properly". But if you display it in IE11, it may work fine (I don't know why). If u find any solutions, please share us